# 0xFFFFFFFFul as (signed) long: UB, Impl-defined or just OK?

Tags: c++

Will this code print -1 on all sane (e.g. 2-s complement arithmetic) 32-bit machines, -1 on LLP64 (i.e. 64-bit Windows, where long is 32-bit) and 4 gig on all 64-bit Unix OS:es (i.e. on LP64 OS:es):

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    long li = 0xfffffffful;

    cout << "size of li: " << sizeof(li) << ", li: " << li << '\n';
}
```

Normally I use well-defined size for relevant variables, and std::numeric_limits instead of 'ul' numeric constants. So I would write something like

```
const uint32_t MAX_INTERVAL = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max(); 
const int64_t some_var = MAX_INTERVAL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have at least 33-bit `long`s there's no problem (or more specifically if 4294967295 can be represented as a `long`). The behavior will be well defined as the number can be represented as a `long`.

If you have 32-bit `long`s there still is little problem. The behavior is then implementation defined which means that the compiler/implementation is mandated to specify the behavior (most probably you would end up with `-1`, but there might exist odd implementation which would yield another result).

The relevant parts of the standard are 4.7 (integral conversions):

> 2. If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo
>      2^n where
>      n
>      is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [
>      Note:
>      In a two’s
>      complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there
>      is no truncation).
>      —end note
>      ]
> 3. If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
>      bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.